# How to remove a M.2 Wi-Fi module that seems to be secured by a non-standard fastener?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, m.2

I've bought a new Lenovo IdeaCentre 5 14ACN6 PC with a AMD Ryzen 5 5600G processor.

I want to detach/remove the M.2 Wi-Fi module card for security reasons. It seems to be a generic Intel Wi-Fi card.

Usually, the M.2 Wi-Fi card is attached with one screw to the motherboard. But in this case, there is some kind of lock or "quick release system" on the screw which I've never seen before. It is a little black plastic rod. The SSD M.2 module has the same lock by the way. I couldn't find anything similar on the internet. I do not know how to call it.

My question is: How do I remove this fastener? I’ve tried pulling and twisting leftwards, but I fear I will break it when I do it the wrong way.

Front view:

[image: Front view.]

The rod is connected to a socket, also note the tie wrap on the right, which is attached to both the rod and the socket

Back view:

[image: Back view.]

Another front view:

[image: Another front view.]

Comment: Find a service manual, usually they are freely available. https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/5-14iob6_5-14acn6_hmm_202104.pdf

Comment: @MarkoBuršič See p77. The service for this model manual only contains instructions for the generic screws. I guess they use a general manual, not an actual one made for this model.

Comment: Looks like a Lenovo specific thing based on what I can see in this listing for an M2 SSD installation kit as seen [here](https://www.newegg.com/p/2BA-003K-001A8) as well as [here](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/memory-and-storage/memory-and-storage-hard-drives/4xf0u53614). Discussion on this item [can be found here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/Where-to-buy-the-plastic-pin-clip-that-holds-down-M-2-SSD-WiFi-card/m-p/5114706). And that has a [clearer picture as well](https://forums.lenovo.com/uploads/topic/202112/163942588682.jpeg).

Comment: @L.A. Rabida  . I guess they use a general manual, not an actual one made for this model.   ...  It is a newer way of fastening cards in a Lenovo desktop computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new way Lenovo is fastening the non-socket end of a card.

Photo here is my Lenovo M70s computer and the card is the 1 TB SSD drive.

It came with a 256GB card. I lifted the plastic plunger, removed the 256GB card, inserted the 1 TB card and pushed plunger back to secure.

This appears to me to be neat way to fasten without screws.

The Lenovo M70s is a desktop computer. Thin laptops will not have room for such a plunger, so either a yet different fastening method or a traditional screw.

[image: Lenovo plastic card securing plunger]

Comment: Thanks, the plunger seems to be fixed very solidly when new. I tried to pull it down sideways first, then it came of. That is probably not the recommended way to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure but it looks like there is a syringe-like plunger on top and a release hook on the shaft (see photo). I don't know if that is an illusion of the gage behind it or some type of release lever when you pull that hook back while pushing the knob down (or pull both). Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the release hook is indeed an illusion, what you see is a tie wrap behind it that is fixed to the plunger of the SSD M.2 module.